# Где найти исходники реализации C++ сущностей и операторов (namespace, new/delete, << / >>)?

Tags: c++, c, реализация

В C++ есть вещи, которых нету в C - пространства имён, пара уникальных операторов (<<, >>, new/delete). Я хочу узнать: как и где они реализованы "под капотом", ведь C++ - это просто чуть допиленный C (в т ч с mangling functions). Ну я и думаю: угу, наверное в stdc++ описаны пространства имён, данные операторы и т д. Но я нашёл там только оператор new (его реализацию). А как реализованы пространства имён? Меня интересуют не исходники `namespace std`, а самой реализации пространств имён как таковой.

Comment: Открывайте исходники gcc clang

Comment: Вы задали вопрос так, как будто это все — просто дополнения в *стандартную библиотеку С*...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он основан на неверной посылке...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет. Чуть допиленный c называется Objective C. А C++ – самостоятельный язык. И даже в Objective C слово `class` прописано в коде компилятора. Оператор `new` Вы нашли по одной простой причине: он обращается к системной функции. Начинайте с реализации области видимости, реализации статической типизации, потом переходите к структурам, а там уже и классы прояснятся, и всё остальное.

Comment: А на какой вопрос вы отвечаете?